chromebook with fresh install of endeavouros (i3wm) has graphical/cpu management (?) issues
choppy video and cpu usage maxxing out on opening browser tabs with a lot going graphically, previous versions of galileo with plasma have basically been plug and play and since I don't quite understand configuring linux well, i take to this forum as to know what to do.
also, my current install has i3wm as galileo neo on plasma is too harsh on my limited resources (its a Lenovo chromebook ideapad 6 celeron n4020 4gb ram), but previous versions ran just fine, also relevant is that I don't tinker a lot unless it is to solve an issue with fresh installation.

does the zen kernel work?

@killertofus i believe its a bit better now with the zen kernel installed
